# Отображение описания объекта MKPinAnnotationView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone

Изучаю работу с MapKit для iphone. Добавляю на объект карту MKMapView объект пин MKPinAnnotationView. При нажатии на пин, выскакивает облако с описанием, однако при обновлении местоположения и перерисовке объекта - облако исчезает. Как заставить облако появляться сразу вместе с пином?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам отвечу: метод называется  "`selectAnnotation:animated`" из `MKMapView`.